# csh while loop in single line

Tags: csh, tcsh

I was trying to get the date printed for the ping command is going, to simulate similar effect as in bash `ping 1.1.1.1 -O | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done`, but could not make it work so far.

Tried the following on a csh shell, but does not work:
`` ping 1.1.1.1 -O | while ( 1 ) echo `date` end ``

What I am missing ?  appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is that the syntax used by csh and tcsh is not nearly as general and flexible as the syntax used by bash and other Bourne-derived shells.

csh does have a special-case syntax for 1-line `if` statements:

```
if (condition) statement
```

but it doesn't have anything similar for loops:

```
% while (1) echo hello
while: Expression Syntax.
```

and it doesn't allow piping a command's output into a loop.

If you *must* use csh/tcsh for some reason, you can write a script to encapsulate your `while` loop and pipe your command's output to that script, or you can invoke an `sh` or `bash` process to do the work for you:

```
csh% bash -c 'ping 1.1.1.1 -O | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done'
```

(I use csh and tcsh, both interactively and for scripting, for a number of years. My own solution was first to start using bash for scripting, and then to give up on tcsh entirely and use bash as my default shell. It's a bit of a learn curve, and there are *some* tcsh features that aren't quite as convenient in bash, but I recommend it.)

I am legally required to post this link:

https://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/csh.whynot

Answer (score 2):

As Keith pointed out, `tcsh` is rather limited in many ways compared to the Bourne shell. But in this particular case you can do something similar by piping the output to e.g. `sed` and prepending every line with a date there:

```
> ping -O 127.0.0.1 | sed "s/^/`date` /"
Sun Apr 19 14:12:28 WITA 2020 PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
Sun Apr 19 14:12:28 WITA 2020 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
Sun Apr 19 14:12:28 WITA 2020 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
Sun Apr 19 14:12:28 WITA 2020 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
```

Remember that most Unix utilities already operate on every line, so doing a `while` loop to operate on every line often isn't needed.

Comment: This doesn't really work, the date command executes only once so the date/time will never change.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Keith/Martin.   Yup,  both answers were equally good.

To the benefit of others:   Both the following satisfy my need, I can use either from a csh/tcsh shell, in fact on any shell:

`bash -c 'ping 127.0.0.1 -O | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done'`

`` ping -O 127.0.0.1 | sed "s/^/`date` /" ``

Comment: At first I thought it was brilliant but the second one with 'sed' doesn't really work. The date command executes only once, so the date/time will never change. Since the output of 'date' includes seconds this gets obvious pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Piping to control structures is an error in C Shell. The workaround to pipe to control structures is to create a script or FIFO file. In my example, I'll use a FIFO.

```
mkfifo ~/fifo
echo 'while 1\
set pong = "$<"\
echo "`date`: $pong"\
end' > ~/fifo & ping -O 1.1.1.1 | ( source ~/fifo )
```